# typo3 adds <p class="bodytext"> </p> randomly

Tags: typo3, typo3-6.2.x

my typo3 adds some

```
<p class="bodytext"> </p>
```

on different places, but I didn't added them, how can I prevent typo3 to do this.

thanks

Comment: new line can cause this: https://www.typo3.net/forum/thematik/zeige/thema/34670/ (german discussion)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This depends on where it is added and what you actually have as content. As your question doesn't offer many information, probably it is about the default setting of RTE fields of content elements.

This is done by the TypoScript configuration of your template. So use the Template module to change the "Setup" part of the sys_template record to include something like:

```
lib.parseFunc_RTE.nonTypoTagStdWrap.encapsLines.addAttributes.P.class >
```

More information on the parseFunc: https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/6.2/Functions/Parsefunc/

More information about templates and TypoScript:
https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptIn45MinutesTutorial/ 
(how to get to the setup field is mentioned in the first chapter)